# How to develop integrations for Acumatica Cloud ERP using their API?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am looking into developing integrations for the Acumatica Cloud ERP. I am developing a SaaS product on Azure which extracts accounting data from various sources. From the documentation provided by Acumatica, I can see that the API connects to a local instance of Acumatica. If I were to connect to a local instance I would need to use some sort of gateway which connects to a local machine. I also had to install a local instance myself to be able to create a client application and use OAuth 2.0.

I am having issues to understand how to create integration with Acumatica.
Do I need to know the instance name / URL of each of my clients? Do I need to have a local instance running to be able to use Acumatica APIs? Can client Acumatica instances be publicly accessed? If the client using authorization code flow, authorizes my application to extract data from Acumatica, what is the Acumatica ERP URL that I should be using? Mine or the client's? The documentation always uses localhost to connect to an API.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any of the Apis provided by Acumatica:

- Contract Based REST (Recommended)
- Contract Based SOAP
- Screen Based SOAP

You only need the a set of credentials and the URL of the site to communicate with it from the outside. By set of credentials I mean that the credentials that you use need to be able to access and perform the appropriate action on the Acumatica screen that you want to integrate with.

You can find more information on how to do so on the help web site at the following link:

https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/(W(12))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=ff22837c-cd3a-410e-b768-88ca6e53b165

It is the Development Integration Guide

**Edit**
Since you are mentioning Authorization Code Flow in the comment, here is the link that contains more information

https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/(W(14))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=ff780860-09c2-46c9-bdd7-c6c3b1fc442c

On that screen you will see the following information:

*After the user is authenticated in Acumatica ERP, the client application receives an authorization code, exchanges it for an access token, and then uses the access token to work with data in Acumatica ERP.*

Which means that even if your application does not handle the user credentials, the users will need a set of credentials in order to connect the application to the Acumatica site. The user used here will defined the access rights that the application has.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify, what do you mean by the "URL of the site to communicate"? Will every Acumatica instance have its own URL. In that case, do we need to create a separate client application on every Acumatica instance? We will be using authorization code flow as to not handle client's credentials (just use the client id and client secret). Why are credentials required here?

Comment: Each Acumatica instance is a web site on its own, so it will have its own URL.

Comment: For the Application, it depends on the need, you can make a single application that would be able to handle all the site or a single application that you could configure with a different URL so that each instance of your application serves a different Acumatica site.

Comment: I have added more information for the Autorization Code flow and User credentials in the Edit to my answer